# Percentages of rows

Tags: mysql

Let "total" the result of following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT C1) from T where <something>
```

("something" is a long condition over columns of T).

Let "partial1" the result of:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT C1) from T where <something> AND C2>10.
```

and "partial2" the result of:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT C1) from T where <something> AND C3>20.
```

there are a better way to write a query that returns the ratios "partial1/total" and "partial2/total"? If total is zero, any usual default value could be valid (null, -1, 1, 100, ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to have this done at MySql level, you could try something like :

```
SELECT
    partial1/total,
    partial2/total
FROM (
    SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT C1) as total,
        COUNT(DISTINCT IF(C2>10, C1, NULL)) as partial1,
        COUNT(DISTINCT IF(C3>20, C1, NULL)) as partial2
    FROM T
    WHERE <something>
) as tmp
;
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know the possibility of DISTINCT with IF. is it NULLl value accounted as one "distinct" value or ignored in the count?

Comment: Yes, NULL values are ignored in COUNT(DISTINCT ...)

You can do this simple test to check :
CREATE TABLE A (a INT DEFAULT NULL);
INSERT INTO A VALUES (1),(2),(3), (NULL),(4),(1),(2),(3),(NULL);
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a) FROM A;

COUNT(DISTINCT a) should return 4 => NULL are ignored